Connect a SharePoint online calendar using "Connect to Outlook" on IOS
I have an Event list and i can use the "Connect to Outlook" to connect a SharePoint online event list to my outlook:-

but on my MAC machine, this options will be disabled.. so how i can Connect a SharePoint online calendar using "Connect to Outlook" on IOS?? Thanks

I'm sorry, but the "Connect to Outlook" feature is not available on iOS devices. This feature is only available on Windows devices.
